# how to decrease calling database for improving speed in fetching data?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, performance, entity-framework-6

I'm working on my project and I need improve speed of fetching data
for example in admin panel we have a lot of menus. if admin click on `menu1` data will load on table and after that admin user click on another menu and again call database and so on... because every time we have to fetch data from database and it will cause to become slow.I want to know how to improve speed of my project.
some persons offer Cache layer 2. Please, I need your help.

Comment: Your question is very general. Please be more specific.

Comment: @FLICKER, I fact , I want to decrease call database from disk because every time we have to read data from disk and it has cost in speed fetching data.

Comment: Simply repeating a vague description is not helping identify a solution. You might be able to cache data but if you need it to be real time this can be a challenge at time also. Maybe what you really need to get the queries faster so the load time isn't a big deal. There are so many possibilities here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is general and there is therefore no specific answer that can address it. However i'll attempt to answer it this way.
Performance bottlenecks can be caused by a number of factors, which my include the way your code was written, server environments issues or the way you wrote your queries to fetch data from the db. I suggest that you look at my blog where i address all these issues in details.
[Coding with System Performance in mind](http://kamoga.net/coding-with-system-performance-in-mind/)